# Передача дополнительных переменных в роутер

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Доброго!

Не совсем ещё втянулся в прелести Node.JS, потому туплю..

В принципе, тривиальный сервер **app.js**:

```
router = require('./routes'); // Каталог с роутерами
var isDebug = true; // Переменная для примера (которую и хочется передать)
var port = 666;
var app = express();
app.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('SERVER STARTED AT PORT: ' + port);
});
router(app, connection, isDebug); // Передали переменую
```

Далее, в **./routes/index.js**:

```
var users = require('./users'); // Куда будем отсылать
module.exports = function (app, isDebug) {
  app.get('/users', users.login); // <-- Вот как именно сюда передать isDebug???
};
```

Очередным параметром - не хочет, ругается:

> Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object
>   Boolean]

А если далать сразу **./routes/index.js**, к примеру, так:

```
module.exports = function (app, connection, isDebug) {
  app.get('/users', function (req, res) {
    if (isDebug) console.log('Trying auth...');
  });
};
```

Всё работает, но так накопится очень много кода в **./routes/index.js**, который хотелось бы разделить..
Для примера, **./routes/user.js**:

```
var login = function (req, res) {
  if (isDebug) console.log('Trying auth...');
};
module.exports.login    = login;
```

Всё, естесственно, упрощено.
Как бы это поизящнее оформить, посоветуйте, пожалуйста, коллеги?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из простых вариантов добавления неких дополнительных параметров в обработку запроса - middleware. Например в корневом роутере:

```
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  req.yourVar = "something";
  req.isDebug = true;
  next();
});
```

или на уровне приложения

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  req.yourVar = "something";
  req.isDebug = true;
  next();
});
```

Дополнительную информацию можно найти [здесь](http://expressjs.com/ru/guide/using-middleware.html)

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за помощь, [Andrew Paramoshkin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/32300/andrew-paramoshkin) и [Юрий Пирогов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/240809/%D0%AE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2)!
Поставили мне мозги на место))
Получилось так (вкратце):

**app.js**

```
var express         = require('express'),
    router          = require('./routes');
var app = express();
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  req.isDebug = true;
  next();
});
app.listen(666);
router(app);
```

**./routes/index.js**

```
var users = require('../routes/users');
module.exports = function (app) {
  app.get('/', users.login);
};
```

**./routes/users.js**

```
module.exports.login = function (req, res) {
  console.log('isDebug: ' + req.isDebug);
  res.status(200).json({ "isDebug": req.isDebug });
};
```